# In the Flutter geocoding package, specify the default language, but not English

Tags: flutter, geocoding

I use the geocoding package to convert geolocation into an address. Conversion takes place in two ways (in the language used by the device, or in the settings (only English). I want to use the Ukrainian language, even if the device is not in Ukrainian. Does anyone know how to do it? I would like to specify the language of the application as Ukrainian! even if the device language itself is different. Does anyone know how to fix it??

Comment: You can change your device's region and language from system settings

Comment: @DhrumilShah yes, I understand, but I am interested in how to make these settings default in my application. Since the user will not change the language of his device in order to use some options in my application

Comment: @DhrumilShah ie my goal is to make mine added only for one country. So I decode the address there and the geocoder's answer must always be in the same language.